# Present or dismiss modal view controller in landscape orientation

Tags: ipad, landscape, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an iPad app with a view of a UIViewController with 3 subview (3 UIViewController). If i present or dismiss a modal view controller in portait orientation I get the view controller with the right frame. If I present or dismiss the modal view controller in landscape orientation i get a wrong frame ("{{0, -256}, {748, 1024}}").

Comment: Do you use SplitViewController ?

Comment: No. I'm managing the three subview manually.

Comment: Does it happens even if you opened and closed the modal view controller in the same direction or only after a change?

Comment: I get this problem only if I open or close the view when it's in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this same issue. I suspect it's because we're manually managing the view hierarchy and not properly accounting for orientation changes. I'll post any addition discovery, but so far I've found that you can correct the modal view controller after it's presented like so:

```
// Display modal dialog view controller "detailNav"
[self presentModalViewController:detailNav animated:YES];     
// Create a custom frame for this view, optional, but needs to be set after presenting
detailNav.view.superview.frame = customRect;                  
// Recenter the view, for example to the center of your apps main window
CGPoint center = myApp.window.center;
detailNav.view.superview.center = center;
```